# Initialize deque efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, copy, deque

I am using a `deque` to store data that is going to be processed. The processing only starts when the deque is full so in a first step I fill my buffer the following way:

```
from collections import deque
import numpy as np

my_deque = deque(maxlen=10)
dims = (20, 20)
my_deque.extend([np.ones(dims)] * 10)
```

However, when I do this and I modify one of the elements of `my_deque`, all elements of `my_deque` are modified.

One alternative I found to avoid this issue is to initialize my `deque` the following way

```
for i in range(10):
    my_deque.append(np.ones(dims))
```

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Edit: One example of modification that create the issue is the following

```
my_deque[7][2, :] = 0
```

After this line of code, the third row of every element of `my_deque` is a row of zeros, not just the one at index 7

Comment: > *"However, when I do this and I modify one of the elements of my_deque, all elements of my_deque are modified."* Does that actually happen with e.g., `my_deque[-1] = [np.zeros(dims)]` I think only the last index will change.

Comment: @SashSinha, I added an example of modification

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny, this creates only one element and defeats the purpose of using a deque which serves as a circular buffer for me

Comment: `[np.ones(dims)]*5` makes a list with 5 references to the same array.  That's a basic property of the list 'multiply'

Comment: `my_deque.extend(list(np.ones(dims)))` would make list action the 3d array more explicit.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny, I had not seen it, indeed it works as expected, Thanks. You can post an answer if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MichaelSzczesny's comment was the right answer, it seems to have been deleted so I post it here:

```
from collections import deque
import numpy as np

my_deque = deque(maxlen=10)
dimensions = (10, 20, 20)
my_deque.extend(np.ones(dimensions))
```